# Get list of custom object in RemedyForce

Tags: custom-object, java, android

I have custom object in my RemedyForce `abc__c` and would like to get list of it.

Tried this code:

```
SearchResult sr = con.search(
                    "FIND {00008137} IN abc__c FIELDS RETURNING abc__c(Id, Name)");
```

but it returns

> [InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault
>   exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='sObject type
>   'abc__c' is not supported. If you are attempting
>   to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity
>   name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the
>   appropriate names.'

Tried this code too and it returns:

```
String sql = "SELECT Id, Name FROM abc__c LIMIT 10";
QueryResult result = con.query(sql);
```

> [InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault 
>   exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='sObject type
>   'abc__c' is not supported.'] row='-1' column='-1'
>   ]]

Anyone can advise how to get list of my custom object?

Answer (score 0):

If the object is part of a managed package, it will have a namespace prefix. If the namespace is `BMCServiceDesk`, the object API name will be `BMCServiceDesk__abc__c`. This will apply to any custom fields within the object as well:

```
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, BMCServiceDesk__Custom_Field__c'
    + ' FROM BMCServiceDesk__abc__c LIMIT 10';
```

Comment: Yes correct, actually the mistake is very silly. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this solved, actually the endpoint that is used in my application is wrong, that's why the custom object is not visible to logged-in user.